# How to create a lotus notes document from a dxl file, with win32com in Python?

Tags: lotus-notes, pywin32

I have export a lotus notes document into a dxl file.

Now, I want to read the exported dxl file in another lotus notes id. How to create a lotus notes document from the dxl file?

Grammar of lotus script seems not suitable for python win32com.

Comment: You have data that was exported from Notes into DXL and you want to read it back into Notes using Python and COM? That seems like a very unexpected choice to me, not a good choice, and in most cases it certainly wouldn't be a necessary choice. Can you tell me why you are not using Lotus Notes and LotusScript for this?

Comment: I have two lotus notes mail accounts in two different dominos, and login on different PCs.  Because of our company's security rules, It can not send mails directly.  Therefore, I tried using a dxl document as a temporary file for transferring.

Comment: As long as you have access to a Domino Designer client that connects to the second Domino system, you should not need to resort to Python. Do a transfer of the DXL file to the PC with Domino Designer for the second Domino system., then write and run a LotusScript agent on that PC to import the DXL.

Answer (score 0):

The HCL Domino Designer Help provides detailed information about LotusScript/COM/OLE Classes and has a lot of examples on how to use them. The documentation can be accessed online [here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_LOTUSSCRIPT_NOTES_CLASSES.html).

Use [NotesSession](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html) and [NotesDXLImporter](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDXLIMPORTER_CLASS.html) as a starting point.

DXL information (text, file) can be imported into a target database by creating an instance of NotesDXLImporter using NotesSession.CreateDXLImporter and calling NotesDXLImporter.Import on the created instance. Options to be used for the import can be set on NotesDXLImporter.

The following code snippet originates from the HCL Domino Designer help.

```
Sub Initialize
  Dim session As New NotesSession
  Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Dim dbCopy As NotesDatabase
  Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
  filename$ = Left(db.FileName, Len(db.FileName) - 4)
  
  REM Open dxl file named after current database
  Dim stream As NotesStream
  Set stream = session.CreateStream
  If Not stream.Open("c:\dxl\" & filename$ & ".dxl") Then
    Messagebox "Cannot open " & filename$,, "Error"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If stream.Bytes = 0 Then
    Messagebox "File did not exist or was empty",, filename$
    Exit Sub
  End If
  
  REM Create new database named current database   + "Copy"
  Set dbCopy = New NotesDatabase("", "")
  Call dbCopy.Create("", filename$ & "Copy", True)
  
  REM Import DXL into new database
  Dim importer As NotesDXLImporter
  Set importer = session.CreateDXLImporter(stream, dbCopy)
  importer.ReplaceDBProperties = True
  importer.ReplicaRequiredForReplaceOrUpdate = False
  importer.ACLImportOption = DXLIMPORTOPTION_REPLACE_ELSE_IGNORE
  importer.DesignImportOption = DXLIMPORTOPTION_CREATE
  Call importer.Process
End Sub
```

I have never done Notes COM API programming using Python's win32com but using VisualBasic and C#. Technically there should be no difference.